# Typescript check if email is valid

Tags: regex, angular, typescript

I want to check if the provided email id is valid or not in typescript.I am trying to use a pattern to validate the email but it's not working.Please help.Thanks in advance.

Ts code:

```
checkemail='/^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/';

validate(email:string)              
if (email.match(this.checkEmail)) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: `checkemail=/^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;`, do not use quotation marks around a regex literal.

Comment: Without quotation I'm getting unterminated regular expression error

Comment: You are not using it as I showed. It works as I have written it.